# I got 'BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted' in iOS 9

Tags: ios, delegates, uitextview, ios9

I've developed a social media app.

After iOS 9 launched, I've got a message

`BSXPCMessage received error for message: Connection interrupted
 XPC connection interrupted
Terminating since there is no system app.`

and the simulator reboots by itself. and a real iPhone too.

when I touched `UITextView` on `UIToolbar` in CommentViewController. it's like text input UI of Message App, the base iOS app.

`SIGKILL` always occurs at any of lines in `textViewDidBeginEditing:` of `UITextView`'s delegate methods, but not happen in textViewShouldBeginEditing:

[image]

But still works well in iOS 8.

[THChatInput](https://github.com/skela/THChatInput), [SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController), [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController)
, etc, I used many libraries, but all of those show me same crash.

I've already read a few of articles about this bug here, but their problem were caused by using CoreImage. unfortunately, I don't use anything about CoreImage

I appreciate in advance for helping me. Thank you.

Comment: now I become crazy, I replace UITextView as UITextField not using any libraries, but it's also happened!!! but I can get more logs, thankfully.

_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)

Answer (score 0):

I've found what causes this problem.

I've used a library called 'SWRevealViewController' for drawer menu in my project.
this is a wrapper class of view controller, so it includes some of view controllers and make a hierarchy.

In previous iOS9, it doesn't cause any problem.

In iOS9, its hierarchy of view controllers cause a problem, when popping up keyboard. it doesn't appear in other ordinary iOS9 project.

I don't say that some library I use have bugs, but some problems may be occured in iOS9.